# MySQL: Is it possible to JOIN the GROUP-BY'd results to two SELECTs?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have two separate SELECT statements which are both GROUP-BY'd separately e.g.:

```
SELECT x, y, z FROM a GROUP BY x
SELECT x, n, o FROM b GROUP BY x
```

I would very much like to JOIN these two SELECTs together to combine their columns, such as:

```
SELECT x as x1, y, z FROM a GROUP BY x 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT x as x2, n, o FROM b GROUP BY x)
ON x1=x2;
```

Is this possible?  I ask because MySQL is complaining

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN
>   SELECT 
>       x as x2

If this is possible, any thoughts on what's wrong with my syntax?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works

```
select * from (
    (select 1 a,2 b,3 c) t1 left join (select null a,2 b,5 c) t2 on (t1.b=t2.b)
);
```

Alternatively,

```
select * from (
    (select 1 a,2 b,3 c) t1 left join (select null a,2 b,5 c) t2 using (b)
);
```

Both result in

```
+---+---+---+------+---+---+
| a | b | c | a    | b | c |
+---+---+---+------+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | NULL | 2 | 5 |
+---+---+---+------+---+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways that you can achieve this:

1. Best: Join the tables BEFORE grouping like so:

   ```
   SELECT a.x, y, z, n, o
     FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.x = b.x
    GROUP BY a.x, b.x;
   ```
2. Select from the two queries as sub-queries like so:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM       (SELECT x, y, z FROM a GROUP BY x) AS a
   INNER JOIN (SELECT x, n, o FROM b GROUP BY x) AS b
           ON a.x = b.x;
   ```

Comment: I think (2) is what's he's looking for.

Comment: +1 indeed, #2 is exactly what I wanted - accepted the previous answer as it was first...but thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this query:
`SELECT a.x, a.y, a.z, b.x, b.o, b.n 
FROM a, (SELECT x, n, o FROM b GROUP BY x) as b
WHERE a.x = b.x
GROUP BY a.x;`