# Join 2 Tables that got joined

Tags: mysql, join

I want to join the following 2 tables that I previously joined so I can see the result where it displays the Active and Inactive Subscription side by side in the same window. How?

TABLE 1 (Subscription Table)

CUSTOMER ID | NAME | StartDate | EndDate

TABLE 2 (Client Table)

CUSTID | ... (IRREVELANT)

> This will give me the Number of Active Suscription

```
Select      T1.CustomerID, T1.Name, COUNT(CustomerID) [# Active Subscription]
FROM        #Customer T1
INNER JOIN  #Subscription AS T2
ON          T1.CustomerID = T2.CustID
WHERE       (T2.EndDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY    T1.CustomerID, T1.Name
```

> This will give me the Number of Inative Suscription

```
Select      T1.CustomerID, T1.Name, COUNT(CustomerID) [# Inactive Subscription]
FROM        #Customer T1
INNER JOIN  #Subscription AS T2
ON          T1.CustomerID = T2.CustID
WHERE       (T2.EndDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY    T1.CustomerID, T1.Name
```

~ >> Looking to see CustomerID, Name, #Active Subscriber, # Inactive Subscriber

~ >> Since they have same CustomerID in both table, then I think we can do another join... But do not know how to write it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Is it possible to JOIN the GROUP-BY'd results to two SELECTs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005201/mysql-is-it-possible-to-join-the-group-byd-results-to-two-selects)

Comment: You need to use *conditional aggregation* with `SUM (CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ` in place of `COUNT`.

Comment: You have not told us enough about what you want for us to answer the question. Eg joining the tables "displays the Active and Inactive Subscription side by side" for id-name pairs that are in both tables. Is that adequate? If not, what do you want? Best is to say you want eg (subscription, name, active, inactive) rows where for some c.id,...,s.id,..., id=c.id AND name=c.name AND ... AND (c.id, c.namej,...) IN Customer AND ... . If there are cases you are having problems with then show example input & desired output. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to first do the GROUP and JOIN on a derived table, then perform a CASE aggregation on the output

Try something like this;

```
SELECT

CASE WHEN (T2.EndDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN
T1.CustomerID END AS customer_id_active,
CASE WHEN (T2.EndDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN
T1.Name END AS name_active,
CASE WHEN (T2.EndDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN
COUNT(CustomerID) END AS count_customerID_active,

CASE WHEN (T2.EndDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN
T1.CustomerID END AS customer_id_inactive,
CASE WHEN (T2.EndDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN
T1.Name END AS name_inactive,
CASE WHEN (T2.EndDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN
COUNT(CustomerID) END AS count_customerID_inactive,

FROM
(SELECT * FROM #Customer AS T1 INNER JOIN #Subscription AS T2 GROUP BY T1.CustomerID, T1.Name) AS derived_table
```